# Android Programming - "id cannot be resolved"

Tags: android, eclipse

I understand that R.id is mapped with the button in man.xml. I tried to debug. But I am not able to do the same.

I encountered this error while I was trying to run the code found at this link

http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/05/scan-bluetooth-devices.html

Comment: can you put your logcat output?

Comment: what was the error?Stack trace information needed?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the button is there in main.xml which you are setting in `setContentView(R.layout.main);`

and then try `Build your Project and Clean your Project and then Run`

Comment: Yes buttons are in the main.xml. And the ids used correspond to those defined in main.xml. But am still getting the error. The logcat is giving blank output